# JMS EntityManager Error

Tags: java, spring, jboss, hornetq

I have an application running on JBoss 6.4 that uses JMS queues.  When this application is deployed the first time everything works as expected, but if I redeploy without restarting the server I get the following stacktrace.

```
HQ122001: Unhandled exception thrown from onMessage: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManagerFactory.
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:382) [org.springframework.orm.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371) [org.springframework.transaction.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335) [org.springframework.transaction.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105) [org.springframework.transaction.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [org.springframework.aop.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89) [org.springframework.aop.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [org.springframework.aop.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621) [org.springframework.aop.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.naic.nusa.user.service.UserService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$365b5448.queryLdapForUsername(<generated>) [cglib-nodep.jar:]
at org.naic.nusa.queue.QueueService.checkMessage(QueueService.java:60) [classes:]
at org.naic.nusa.queue.QueueService.access$200(QueueService.java:33) [classes:]
at org.naic.nusa.queue.QueueService$1.onMessage(QueueService.java:239) [classes:]
at org.hornetq.jms.client.JMSMessageListenerWrapper.onMessage(JMSMessageListenerWrapper.java:98)
at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1117)
at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$500(ClientConsumerImpl.java:57)
at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1252)
at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:105)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_71]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_71]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManagerFactory.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.verifyOpen(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:306) [eclipselink.jar:2.4.2.v20130514-5956486]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277) [eclipselink.jar:2.4.2.v20130514-5956486]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:304) [eclipselink.jar:2.4.2.v20130514-5956486]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:282) [eclipselink.jar:2.4.2.v20130514-5956486]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:400) [org.springframework.orm.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:321) [org.springframework.orm.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
... 19 more
```

I know glassfish has had issues with this, but has anyone running jboss / hornetq seen this before?

Comment: Without looking at complete log it is difficult to understand. You should check the log to ensure 1) old application is undeployed 2) Spring context shutdown gracefully 3) on New Deploy EntityManager was initialized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this has anything to do with HornetQ. I suspect you will be better off by posting this issue on JPA forum.